# Unable to Build any program in Windows 10 with Qt Creator 5.12.3

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-c++, qt-creator

I have been running into a recurring error continuously for the last few days when i'm trying to compile a program in my Windows 10 machine. The program was originally written in Linux using Qt 5.10 and GCC and in Linux it worked perfectly for years. Now when i'm trying to compile it in my windows machine its giving me an error saying that MSVC2017 32 Bit has configuration issues.

```
 Qt Creator 4.9.1
Based on Qt 5.12.3 (MSVC 2017, 32 bit)

Built on May 26 2019 21:17:08

From revision 168e91b618

Copyright 2008-2019 The Qt Company Ltd. All rights reserved.
```

Here is the error that is making my life hell as i just can't compile any program in Windows. As i'm a linux only developer so this is the first time i'm seeing such errors as i'm trying to compile it on Windows 10.

```
20:40:28: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.12.4\Tools\mingw730_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project webenginebrowser (kit: Desktop Qt 5.12.4 MSVC2017 32bit)
The kit Desktop Qt 5.12.4 MSVC2017 32bit has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
When executing step "Make"
```

When installing Qt in Windows i've selected the Full package everything that comes under the 5.12.3 tree. Mingw Qt version, clang all are installed.

I've also installed Visual Studio 2017 with C++ tools and every assorted libraries.

I've also ran vcvarshall.bat and opened Qt creator from that terminal but still the same error is coming up and i have no idea left on how to tackle this. I've literally been trying out each solution given by google still the same error.

Please give some solution on how to get my programs compiled in Qt 5.12 in Windows.

Qt Kit Settings

[image]

Comment: Did you already check Kit settings (Tools --> Options --> Kits) in Qt Creator to see if there is a message or hint regarding configuration mismatch ?

Comment: The kit settings shows some of the auto detected compilers. I've attached the screenshot

Comment: Mingw32-make is being invoked instead of nmake which is Visual Studio's make tool. Without knowing the configuration of your other settings it is hard to say what the problem is. My guess is that you have a complex set of overlapping compilers and QtCreators detection is picking mingw32-make for use with VS which isn't compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Finally after trying out all the suggestions i found out that the problem was the messing up of too many libraries in the test machine where i was building the Qt program.
I had to take explicit permission to remove everything and install a fresh Windows 10. After that i only selected the MinGW in the kit and it finally compiled properly.